# Using Apache Thrift with Node.js

Tags: node.js, thrift

I'm trying to use Apache Thrift as an RPC mechanism for node.js. However, the [official Thrift tutorial for node.js](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs/) appears to be incomplete, and doesn't describe how to access Thrift services from node.js. Is it yet possible to use Apache Thrift with Node.js, and is any documentation available anywhere?

If Thrift doesn't yet support node.js, then is there any similar RPC framework that works with node.js?

Comment: I think I found the official documentation (with an examples folder): https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/trunk/lib/nodejs

Comment: Update: The forthcoming 0.9.2 release contains a number of improvements in the JS/node area.

Answer (score 2):

The [tutorial has been updated](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs) with a good example. In case if you are looking for other RPC modules in node, you can have a look at [my answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23852058/774086).